# Orchard module can't be seen in solution

Tags: orchard-modules, orchardcms-1.9

I just installed a new module (by coping module folder to the folder Modules located inside Orchard.Web). I can get its features enabled successfully but I can't see the module project in the solution anywhere (I'm using VS2013).
so How do I get the module seen in solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you confirm that the module is in the modules folder (Orchard.Web\Modules)?  If it is and doesn't show up in Visual Studio, in VS, you can right click on the modules folder and "Add existing project..." then you should be able to see it.

As a future reference, you can use the command prompt to create a new module and use the parameter to include in solution right away:

```
codegen module <module-name> [/IncludeInSolution:true|false]
```